# Почему при попытке просмотра вопроса у меня появляется какой то непонятный интерфейс?

Tags: дефект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]см. скрииншот. Эта проблема только после входа на сайт.

Comment: Хм.. Некоторое время назад такой же вопрос тут видел... Но у меня нормально показывается. Какая ОС, какой браузер? Если в приватном окне смотреть (там расширения не загружаются), то показывается так же?

Comment: Кажется, это из-за рекламного баннера. Заблокируйте рекламу с помощью расширений типа [AdblockPlus](https://adblockplus.org/).

Comment: Это баг. Он зарегистрирован на https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383153/multibyte-characters-for-report-this-ad-string-are-broken  и висит на рассмотрении сотрудниками SO